# Identify inbound SMS numbers not associated with contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms

Our sales team would like to get hold of any SMS that have been sent to our long/short codes that are not associated with a contact.
Ideally we would like to be able to have this as an actionable report that could be emailed to them regularly.
Is it possible to have a report of inbound sms, or a report of both inbound and outbound that includes the subscriber id or similar so we can see those that are not associated with a contact.
When I ran the detailed sms report only 2 had a subscriber ID but the rest were correctly linked to contacts when manually investigated.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build the reports you want, you'll need to use SQL queries in Automation Studio to retrieve data from a data view called [SMSMessageTracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sms_message_tracking.htm&type=0). This is pretty much a more extensive [SMS Message Detail](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_sms_message_detail_report.htm&type=5) Report that has regularly new fields added to it.

It includes both the `Inbound` and `SubscriberKey` fields that would allow you to filter data on them and build the report you want. You could then create an email that pulls the results of this query and sends it to your sales team.